# SQL sp_send_dbmail adding T in date column

Tags: sql, sp-send-dbmail

I have a sp_send_dbmail query that emails a list of results.

Everything works great except the date column is getting a T added where the space is.

It shows fine when i run the query, but when it is used in the sp_send_dbmail its adding the T.

**Example**

`2014-11-06T16:06:24.100`

**Should Be**

`2014-11-06 16:06:24.100`

**Query in the sp_send_dbmail**

```
SELECT
td = [Status],'',
td = [Number],'',
td = [Date] ,'',
td = [Error Message]
FROM [Views].dbo.Errors   
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Can we see you query?

Comment: @Sam added query thats in the `sp_send_dbmail` to the question

Comment: The `T` variant is actually a safer way to represent a datetime value - SQL Server can, occasionally, interpret `nnnn-nn-nn nn:nn:nn` is being in `yyyy-dd-mm...` format instead of `yyyy-mm-dd...` format - but it doesn't get confused when `T` is the separator instead of space.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is there anyway i can remove this? if i do a CONVERT() will this resolve it as i will be defining which date type to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your date-column with **[`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**:

```
SELECT
td = [Status],'',
td = [Number],'',
td = CONVERT(varchar(25), [Date], 21),'',
td = [Error Message]
FROM [Views].dbo.Errors   
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Just thought of this in the comments :) Works